# How to use grep to search for a pattern which starts with a hyphen (-)?

Tags: grep

```
sudo find / -name "*" | xargs grep -sn --color=auto "-j"
```

Above command returns below:

```
grep: invalid option -- 'j'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
...
```

How do I search for string `-j`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `"-j"` is interpreted by `grep` as an argument/option, not as a search pattern, even if you quoted it. To make it to be the pattern for what you want to search, just use `-e`option:

```
sudo find / -name "*" | xargs grep -sn --color=auto -e "-j"
```

or even:

```
sudo find / -name "*" | xargs grep -sn --color=auto -e -j
```

The `-e` argument/option means that the next argument is the pattern. This is from `man grep`:

```
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use  PATTERN  as  the  pattern.   This  can  be  used to specify
          multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with
          a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)
```

Other ways:

- use `--`, as [@Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) said in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/500958/147044), to make `grep` to hnow that the options ended.
- use `\` to escape the hyphen (`-`):

  ```
  sudo find / -name "*" | xargs grep -sn --color=auto "\-j"
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Tell it that the options ended with `--`:

```
sudo find / -name "*" | xargs grep -sn --color=auto -- "-j"
```

Result:

```
Binary file /initrd.img matches
Binary file /lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/ubuntu/media/gspcav1/gspca.ko matches
Binary file /lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/ubuntu/sound/alsa-driver/isa/es1688/snd-es1688.ko matches
Binary file /lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/ubuntu/sound/alsa-driver/pci/ice1712/snd-ice1712.ko matches
/lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/modules.dep:1807:/lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/kernel/fs/nls/nls_euc-jp.ko:
Binary file /lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/kernel/crypto/blowfish.ko matches
Binary file /lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/kernel/fs/nls/nls_euc-jp.ko matches
Binary file /lib/modules/2.6.24-16-server/kernel/fs/nls/nls_cp936.ko matches
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape `-` character using `\`

```
$ sudo find / -name "*" | xargs grep -sn --color=auto "\-j"
```

Also you may want to exclude folders and search only files, add `-type f` to `find`:

```
$ sudo find / -name "*" -type f | xargs grep -sn --color=auto "\-j"
```

Also if you add `-P 4` to `xargs`, it will parallel all execution on 4 processes, and search may be done faster if you have more than 1 cores.

```
$ sudo find / -name "*" -type f | xargs -P 4 grep -sn --color=auto "\-j"
```